# CSS code working differently in IE and Chrome

Tags: css

My code is

```css
.mstrmojo-DocSelector td {
    height: .24in;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    border-right-width: 0.111111em;
    border-bottom-width: 0.111111em
}
```

This is working fine in Chrome but in IE the height is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference, what do you expect, can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: No I can not provide jsfiddle. I am working on microstrategy and this code is to be put in a html box.
I have two tables and I want the height of both of the table cells to be same. In chrome this code works and the both table cells have same height but in explorer it is not.

Comment: you can still provide a jsfiddle with this example, you got the html and css right? Sometimes it's hard to take exactly what your asking for but this is not as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put css code inside a script tag, but in a style one.
I think you should better use too a div with the fixed height inside the td.
Example:

```
<style>
.mstrmojo-DocSelector td {
    border-bottom-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    border-right-width: 0.111111em;
    border-bottom-width: 0.111111em
}

.mstrmojo-DocSelector td div {
    height: .24in;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Script was a mistake. I have written it in my original code. I tried writing div at the end. It did not make any difference.

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle example? 
The div needs to be inside the td